# Android WebDriver. XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'URL'. Origin 'URL' is not allowed by Access- Control-Allow-Origin. at null:1

Tags: java, android, json, webdriver

I am running my automated tests on Nexus 10 (Android 4.2) using Selenium WebDriver and Java. The error I face with is:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'URL1'. Origin 'URL2' is not allowed by Access- Control-Allow-Origin. at null:1
```

- URL1 - back-end which is based on json;
- URL2 - front-end.

This error doesn't occur for FireFox, Chrome, IE 10. But it always occur for WebDriver on Android. Due to it Log in to the system is unavailable. WebDriver is able to click, sendKeys and etc.

So the question is: Is any workaround exists to avoid this issue? May be some settings which I should change for WebDriver? May be someone faced with something like this before. I appreciate any suggestions.

I've tried apk 2.21.0 and 2.32.0.

Comment: Can you show the code that you're running when this error occurs?  Is it launching the browser?

Comment: Code is working fine. Browser is launching and webdriver works (Fills required fields, and presses "Login" button). This is some problem with CORS or JSONP. I am looking for advanced settings of AndroidWebDriver which can help me to work-around this problem. I start browser with `WebDriver driver = new AndroidDriver("http://localhost:8080/wd/hub");`

Comment: This error start to occur right after `driver.get("http://someurl.com");` and occurs every 2 seconds, than stops. And after `WebElement loginButton = driver.findElement(By.id("login"));` `loginButton.submit();` it occurs again. Seems like because of response from back-end and only if credentials were correct. If credentials were incorrect - everything works fine - appropriate alert appears.

Comment: It is not very clear why this error occurs only in android webdriver. Everything works fine with FireFoxDriver, ChromeDriver and even iPhoneDriver...

Comment: Are you trying to load a url with a different domain? Can't tell what you are trying to do but the error message makes me think of the Same Origin Policy

Comment: Domain is the same for each browser.

Comment: can you please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, that was the problem with web sockets. The application is based on web sockets. The point is - Native android browser doesn't support sockets until Android 4.4 and Selenium use exactly native android browser to execute tests.

I've tested the same at emulator with Android 4.4 and everything works fine. Thanks everyone for help.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look on this.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'URL1'. Origin 'URL2' is not allowed by Access- Control-Allow-Origin. at null:1

Adding the following code, app will running correctly.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
  webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
}
```

So, basically this is happening as the `URL1` is **not accessible** by the jquery, Json.

Comment: I use Java6 u43. Do I need to update it? Because now `Build` variable is undefined.

Comment: @Evgeniy, No need to update the JAVA. **Build** is from `import android.os.Build;` and **VERSION_CODES** is from `import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES;`

Comment: Thanks. And what about 'webView' where should I define it?

Comment: webview is your current webView which you are currently using to display the online content.

Comment: How can I initialize "WebView"? I'm using Web Driver to work with browser. I've never used WebView.

Answer (score 1):

As i don't know exactly your code I will give you only an explanation about how I think you could solve the problem, please don't consider it as a real answer, just give it a try :)

I had sometimes this problem, and usually you can fix it in your server using the CORS feature, depending on the server application/framework that you're using you use this CORS in a different way, but basically you need to fill in your response's header from the server following information properly:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Methods
Access-Control-Allow-Headers
```

A very "open" configuration would be:

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods=GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers=Content-Type, Authorization
```